# How do you say "I kidnapped her." in French?

Tags: grammaire

I know the right translation is "**Je lui ai enlevé.**" But shouldn't it be "**Je l'ai enlevé.**"? "She" is a direct object and should therefore be replaced by "**la**". Not "**lui**".

The verb **enlever** is also *not* followed by the preposition à.

So why is lui used? It doesn't make any sense...?

Comment: you don't, you just invite her to a party before she gets off the airport

Comment: in your original sentence, *lui* is neutral. In this context it means `from that person`

Comment: I'm a teensy bit worried how many people are willing to translate  "I kidnapped her" into French at will :)

Comment: Looks like someone has some troubles with an international court.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Your assumption is wrong, *Je lui ai enlevé* means something like *I removed (something) from him/her*.

"I kidnapped her" can be translated by *Je l'ai enlevée* (note the final e).

Comment: Technically, _I removed it from her_ would be _Je le/la lui ai enlevé_. _Je lui ai enlevé_ is an unfinished sentence as it fails to say what exactly was removed from him/her. It's like _I removed <missing> from her_.

Comment: actually in the original sentence there is no mention of gender, nor of what is removed, so I would say *I removed from him/her*, although the object could be implicit from a previous proposition

Comment: @njzk2 Indeed, answer updated

Comment: @sch **technically** *lui* can stand for the sequences *le lui, la lui, les lui*...

Comment: @GAMPUB. In spoken French, you may contract le and lui so that le becomes almost inaudible as in _je l'lui ai pris_ but _je lui ai pris_ is incorrect. You can say _je lui ai parlé_ as it's _I've spoken to her_ not _I've spoken it to her_.

Comment: @sch This not restricted to *le* as seems implied. It works with feminine *la* and plural *les* too.

Comment: @GAMPUB, one may _say_ it, just like one may _say_ _Qu'est-ce t'as fait ?_ in place of _Qu'est-ce que tu as fait ?_ / _Qu'as tu fait ?_, but that's still incorrect, you'd be grilled in a French exam for writing _je lui ai enlevé_ to mean _je les lui ai enlevés_.

Answer (score 4):

You can say

> Je l'ai kidnappée

See the [definition](http://www.larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/kidnapper/45510)

Comment: No, that means, `I kidnapped HIM` you are missing the final `e` that changes the gender.

Comment: +1 for mentioning the fact that "kidnap" also exists in French but please add an e as explained by @JB!

Answer (score 2):

Or, you could say something like "je l'ai prise en otage". I took her hostage - note the "e" at the end of "pris".

Comment: This is hardly the same.

Comment: Disagree - kidnapping for ransom is more or less identical to taking somebody hostage.

Comment: Well, bank robbers taking people hostage are not kidnapping anyone... Parents can kidnap their own children (usually without threatening their lives). This is hardly the same.

Comment: I said kidnapping for ransom. I specifically avoided the case of parents "kidnapping" their own children - one doesn't do that for a ransom. You are correct, about bank robbers taking people hostage - but they're not doing that for money either - in that case, it's a last resort when their bank robbery has gone wrong. It's a fine point, but I stand by my statement that in the case of kidnapping for ransom, it's equivalent to being taken hostage.

Comment: I understand the statement but not its relation to the original question as is.

Comment: Why would you add an "e" to pris? The auxillary verb is avoir; not etre.

Comment: If the object of the phrase "I took" is feminine, then there is an "accord" with the object. La lampe (the lamp). J'ai pris la lampe. I took the lamp. Je l'ai prise. I took it (meaning the lamp). If  I had taken something masculine, then it would be "Je l'ai pris". Je l'ai pris - i.e. I took the thing, i.e. le truc.

Answer (score 2):

Another possibility is to use the verb "ravir". You could say: "Je l'ai ravie", which means exactly "Je l'ai kidnappée" оr "Je l'ai enlevée".

Comment: Beware that "Je l'ai ravie" is ambiguous as it an also be understood as "I pleased her".

Comment: Moreover, the verb "ravir" is mostly used in formal speech, you can find it in the literature but French people rarely use it whereas the word "ravisseur" is used in informal speech.

Comment: @jlliagre - more like "pleased" as in "ravished" :-) - "je lui ai plu" is "I pleased him/her".

Comment: "Je lui ai ravi" is not ambiguous however (because it does not make any sense with meaning "pleased"). It's more informal. Notice the missing final "e" in that case, since "lui" is a indirect object complement whose gender is not related to "her" but to whom lost her (unknown in the OP question hence masculine/neutral).

Comment: If you're not a proficient speaker of French you should avoid using this. It would only lead to misunderstanding.